# Android: set text for TextView in ListView from DialogFragment

Tags: android

i had problem with set text for ListView from DialogFragment. My code as below:
- i have a TimePickerFragment as below

```
package com.working.unility;

import java.util.Calendar;

import com.working.dailyreminder.R;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public  TimePickerFragment() {

    }
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = ca.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = ca.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hour, int minute) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity()().findViewById(R.id.content);
        textView.setText(" " + hour);
    }

}
```

And the TaskFragment class to call TimePickerFragment as below

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.working.unility.TimePickerFragment;

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView mListView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_task_item);
        String[] list_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_title_task);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.task_row, R.id.title, list_title);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                TimePickerFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time set");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }   

}
```

In the ListView, i have 2 TextView include: title & content. Now i want to set text to TextView id content for ListView by calling TimePickerFragment as above but the TimePickerFragment cannot identify content id row and always set text for the first row in the ListView. So how can i solve the problem?

thank you

Comment: Which textview id is not identified ? In which layout your `TextView` resides ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try passing the view to the `TimePickerFragment` in constructor. Then in `onTimeSet` method, call `setText` on the view.

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    private View mView;

    public  TimePickerFragment(View view) {
        mView = view;
    }
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = ca.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = ca.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hour, int minute) {
        if(mView instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView) mView).setText(" " + hour);
    }
}
```

Change the call in `OnItemClickListener` like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    TimePickerFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment(view);
    timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time set");
}
```

Comment: Thank for your solutions. i did as your suggestion but i got the error This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.working.unility.TimePickerFragment), and when i add default contrucstor, the problem is that "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead"

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this problem. What you can do then is to pass the id / position of the `ListView` item to the `Fragment` using `Fragment#setArgument(Bundle)` and in `onTimeSet` change the `ListView` data source, followed by `Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: but ListView in the MainFragment so how to change it on TimePickerFragment? is there any way to get text string back from TimePickerFragment?